# Is it possible to update a subdocument via Mongoose using an $inc?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose, upsert

I have a document that looks like:

```
{
    "personName": "Some name",
    "metaDetails": {
        "visits": 1,
        "otherMeta": 32
    }
}
```

Using `Mongoose` for `Node.js`. I'd like to update (or insert) the visits count. Here's what I have so far. I've read about the [$ positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) but I might be way off:

```
updObj = {}
newKeyString = "metaDetails.$.visits"
updObj[newKeyString] = 1


Person.update {personName: "Some name}, {$inc: updObj}, {upsert: true}, (err, updRes) ->
```

This doesn't appear to actually update or insert any documents however. Any help?

**EDIT: Added the model**

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  personName:
    type: String, index: true, unique: true
  metaDetails: []
```

This is my model. `metaDetails` is intentionally not defined beyond just an array because the data within can be highly variable

Comment: That looks right to me. I will check it on my end and see what is up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you put the $ operator inside another object. In javascript it ll become a associative array, but $inc accepts the string equivalent of it.

Try this function

```
Person.update {personName: "Some name"}, {$inc:  "metaDetails.$.visits" : 1 }, {upsert: true}, (err, updRes) ->
```

Comment: This doesn't work simply because I don't have `visits` specified. see my edit above

Comment: @Shamoon, we only can answer based on what you mentioned in your question.. how can i know that you made a mistake somewhere else.. just wanted to know after adding the visits, your initial query works fine?

Comment: My mistake. I can't add the `visits`. That's the problem, since my `metaDetails` are super variable and can be... anything

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Mongoose syntax as I generally use the native driver directly, but your JS update should look like:

`db.Person.update({"personName": "Some name", "metaDetails.visits": {$exists: true}}, {"$inc": {"metaDetails.$.visits": 1}})`

This might be analogous, I'm not sure (feels like there are missing brackets):

`Person.update {personName: "Some name", $exists: "metaDetails.visits": true}, {$inc:  "metaDetails.$.visits" : 1 }`

Setting upsert to true will create a duplicate personName record if there is no metaDetails object with a visits key. Succinctly, the $ operator in the update requires that the field be part of the predicate.